# WP Multisite /china/ blocked in China

Tags: wordpress, multisite, great-firewall-of-china

I am struggling to know why my Wordpress website is blocked in China.

Services I have running on the root site http://example.com that I believe are being blocked are:

- Google Maps,
- Google Analytics
- Google Recaptcha
- Vimeo
- Facebook/Twitter share buttons

My multisite subsite I have added in a whole bunch of conditionals for the above services to turn them off for http://example.com/china/ however this is still  blocked.

Not sure how china firewall blocking works, do they search on keywords in your code? like "recaptcha" "google" "facebook" "vimeo" etc and/or does it grab the resources from the root site?

I have viewed some other websites page source on china server which are not blocked and see google analytics, google maps, facebook icons etc, so I am a bit confused.. ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: I have looked in my "Sources" tab from inspect element there is a top/github.io reference - china blocks github references - however I cannot find this - i suspect is it in source maps file mm not sure how to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by an infinite redirect that was happening. We used this to identify the cause https://www.websitepulse.com/tools/china-firewall-test

Answer (score 0):

How do you make sure your site is blocked in china?

Based on my experience it is possible that your IP address is being used as a proxy

Comment: If you have a question ask it in a comment instead of posting an answer.